# Почему-то при обращении к указателю массива для нахождение длины выводит 8(то.e 2 int элемента,а нужно 16(то бишь 4))

Tags: c++, массивы, функции, указатели, sizeof

```
int Convert_mas_num(int *mas)
{   

    int del = 10;
    int num = mas[0];
    std::cout << sizeof(mas) << std::endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= sizeof(mas)/sizeof(mas[0]); i++)
    {   
        num += mas[i]*del;
        del *= 10;
        std::cout << i << std::endl;
    }
    return num;
}


int main()
{   
    int mas[4] = {2, 4, 0, 1};
    int *p_mas = mas;
    std::cout << Convert_mas_num(p_mas);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: В C++ для решения задач с массивами лучше использовать std::vector / std::array. Эти штуки прекрасно осведомлены о своем размере, а также поддерживают уйму полезных методов. 
Ваш же подход (как и большинство того что написано в посредственных учебниках), отностится к миру C

Comment: пора вводить метку с+ или с с классами и помечать такие вопросы

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Пора делать какой-то стандартный вопрос и закрывать остальные, как дубли...

Что вы передаете в функцию?

```
int Convert_mas_num(int *mas)
```

указатель. Какой размер указателя? Обычно 4 байта для 32-разрядной платформы, 8 байт - для 64-разрядной.

Итак, ваше

```
sizeof(mas)/sizeof(mas[0])
```

равно на 64-разрядной платформе 8/4 == 2.

Вместе с указателем вам надо передавать в функцию и размер вашего массива.

Comment: Тимур, не забудьте поставить галочку Harry!

Comment: и стрелочку, т.к он трудился для Вас